# Why does page hang/timeout with apache2, mod_wsgi, django, in virtual environment and under non-privileged user

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

When I go to 52.1.65.249, the page hangs or times out.  I have a django project located under a non-root user at /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto.

I have the same problem on two servers running ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.8 and ubuntu 15.04 and python 2.7.9.  I believe the mod_wsgi on PyPi was compiled using python 2.7.8, so for the server running python 2.7.9 I downloaded from Github and compiled using the version of python on my server.  Everything was working fine until I updated my packages all at once, so I'm not sure which package update broke things.  I suspect that it has to do with the fact that I'm not using the new version of mod_wsgi correctly, but I'm not sure and I want to keep my Django project under a non-root user without access to Apache files.

My custom conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/bkto.conf is:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/projbkto/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/usrbkto/vent
WSGIPythonPath /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto

LogLevel info


<Directory /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/projbkto>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/media/
Alias /static/ /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/static/

<Directory /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The apache error.log is:

```
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.082545 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32630:tid 140666831587200] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.4.12 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.082692 2015] [mpm_event:info] [pid 32630:tid 140666831587200] AH00490: Server built: Mar  9 2015 11:53:48
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.082713 2015] [core:notice] [pid 32630:tid 140666831587200] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.083297 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Python home /home/usrbkto/venv.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.083401 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Initializing Python.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.089325 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Python home /home/usrbkto/venv.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.089442 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Initializing Python.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.181394 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.181479 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Adding '/home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto' to path.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.182781 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.186652 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.186718 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Adding '/home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto' to path.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:41.212429 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666831587200] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:47.101220 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666698360576] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Create interpreter 'ip-172-31-4-180.ec2.internal|'.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:47.102574 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666698360576] mod_wsgi (pid=32634): Adding '/home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto' to path.
[Mon Jun 01 05:14:47.104087 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32634:tid 140666698360576] [client 64.94.31.206:47918] mod_wsgi (pid=32634, process='', application='ip-172-31-4-180.ec2.internal|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/projbkto/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jun 01 05:16:46.847615 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666612999936] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Create interpreter 'ip-172-31-4-180.ec2.internal|'.
[Mon Jun 01 05:16:46.848995 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666612999936] mod_wsgi (pid=32632): Adding '/home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto' to path.
[Mon Jun 01 05:16:46.850506 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 32632:tid 140666612999936] [client 166.137.244.128:61084] mod_wsgi (pid=32632, process='', application='ip-172-31-4-180.ec2.internal|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/projbkto/wsgi.py'.
```

The wsgi.py file at /home/usrbkto/bkto/projbkto/projbkto/wsgi.py is:

```
"""
WSGI config for projbkto project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projbkto.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod_wsgi versions of PyPi are source code and not binaries. To say the mod_wsgi on PyPi is compiled with a certain Python version doesn't make any sense as they are compiled on your own system using whatever Python version you have.

Anyway, read this and try the remedy given:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

This is the usual fix for lock ups caused by Python C extensions which aren't coded properly to work in sub interpreters.

Also stop using embedded mode and use daemon mode instead:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

If these don't help, indicate whether it is easily reproducible or random.

Comment: You are correct, sir.  I added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to bkto.conf and then restarted apache and it worked. Thank you very much.